# is this equality of serie right?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Consider the following:  $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n|=L<\infty $$
I want to bound the series $\sum_{n=1}|a_n/n^2|$, I know that $\sum_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, so my intuition tells me that: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\frac{a_n}{n^2}|=L\frac{\pi^2}{6} $$ or at  least change this equality for a $\leq$, but I am not sure if this is right. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Cauchy–Schwarz inequality we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\frac{a_n}{n^2}\right|\le \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n^2} \cdot \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n^4}}\le L\frac{\pi^2}{\sqrt{90}}<L\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Answer (score 0):

Noting that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n|=L<\infty $$
implies $|a_n|\le L$. Hence
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\frac{a_n}{n^2}|\le\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{L}{n^2}= L\frac{\pi^2}{6} .$$